# Lagging Android Application- Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

My android application keeps lagging whenever i navigate from one activity to the other. I had an idea it could be the cause of large images. With respect to that, i decided to use Picasso and later switch to Glide for efficient loading and scaling of images to avoid lagging and slow performance. But it seems it none of these packages are working smoothly for me.

Since i had a thought it could be my some of my images i decided to replace all my images with a icon of size (200 bytes) and still the application lags when i moves from activity to another. When i click on the navigation drawer left, it lags for some seconds before draws fully to the left and the data appears. Obviously, the app doesn't lag when i don't perform any data call.

Looking in my log cat, this how my application is functioning. Someone please help me out to resolve this as i currently do not know where the issue is coming from.

I have 3 activities.

1) Main Launcher currently has no data in. It is only has a toolbar and the navigation drawer left

2) 2nd Activity fetches images and text from the internet.

3) Displays images(circleImageView) and text(names) of contacts

**log for main launcher**

```
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment[0x7e2e0160] -> System.Core[0x7efed490]: 4
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_get_array_length'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_get_array_length'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_get_array_length'.
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref peaceApp.Droid[0x7c7bc640] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView[0x7e7c8678]: 2
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView[0x7e7c8678] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat[0x7ddf0878]: 3
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref peaceApp.Droid[0x7c7bc640] -> mscorlib[0x737bb290]: 48
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref peaceApp.Droid[0x7c7bc640] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI[0x7e14d710]: 3
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_new_string'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_new_string'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_new_string'.
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref peaceApp.Droid[0x7c7bc640] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Design[0x7e27a2d0]: 2
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref peaceApp.Droid[0x7c7bc640] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment[0x7e2e0160]: 3
[dalvikvm-heap] Grow heap (frag case) to 28.817MB for 9000016-byte allocation
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_object_method_a'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_object_method_a'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_object_method_a'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_object_method'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_object_method'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_object_method'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method_a'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method_a'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method_a'.
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Android.Support.Design[0x7e27a2d0] -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI[0x7e14d710]: 4
[Adreno-EGL] <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
[Adreno-EGL] OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.07
[Adreno-EGL] Build Date: 01/22/14 Wed
[Adreno-EGL] Local Branch: base_au149_adreno_au169_patches
[Adreno-EGL] Remote Branch: 
[Adreno-EGL] Local Patches: 
[Adreno-EGL] Reconstruct Branch: 
[OpenGLRenderer] Enabling debug mode 0
[RecyclerView] No adapter attached; skipping layout
[RecyclerView] No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

**2nd Activity**

```
[Mono] Unloading image System.Reflection.dll [0x82696200].
[Mono] Image addref System.Reflection[0x82695838] -> System.Reflection.dll[0x7ef44a48]: 5
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: 'System.Reflection.dll.config'.
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Reflection/System.Reflection.config'.
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Newtonsoft.Json[0x7db5a818] -> System.Reflection[0x7ef45668]: 3
[Mono] Unloading image System.Linq.dll [0x82696200].
[Mono] Image addref System.Linq[0x82696048] -> System.Linq.dll[0x7eff61a0]: 5
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: 'System.Linq.dll.config'.
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Linq/System.Linq.config'.
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Newtonsoft.Json[0x7db5a818] -> System.Linq[0x7efec330]: 3
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Newtonsoft.Json[0x7db5a818] -> System.Reflection.Extensions[0x7f01cad0]: 3
[Mono] Image addref System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter[0x826daa38] -> System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll[0x826d7e20]: 2
[Mono] Prepared to set up assembly 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter' (System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll)
[Mono] Assembly System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter[0x826daa38] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT: image 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/com.companyname.peaceapp.peaceapp-25/libaot-System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll.so" not found
[Mono] AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/com.companyname.peaceapp.peaceapp-25/libaot-System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll.so" not found
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll.config'.
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.config'.
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Newtonsoft.Json[0x7db5a818] -> System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter[0x826daa38]: 2
Loaded assembly: System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll [External]
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter[0x826daa38] -> System[0x82665978]: 4
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.ObjectModel[0x82664640] -> mscorlib[0x737bb290]: 56
[Mono] Image addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0x83e5cb80] -> System.Runtime.Serialization.dll[0x83e457f0]: 2
[Mono] Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization' (System.Runtime.Serialization.dll)
[Mono] Assembly System.Runtime.Serialization[0x83e5cb80] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT: image 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/com.companyname.peaceapp.peaceapp-25/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so" not found
[Mono] AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/com.companyname.peaceapp.peaceapp-25/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so" not found
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.config'.
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Runtime.Serialization/System.Runtime.Serialization.config'.
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives[0x83acfff8] -> System.Runtime.Serialization[0x83e5cb80]: 2
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0x83e5cb80] -> mscorlib[0x737bb290]: 57
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.Serialization.dll [External]
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.Core[0x7efed490] -> System[0x82665978]: 5
[Mono] Image addref System.Linq.Expressions[0x83e78c00] -> System.Linq.Expressions.dll[0x83e94518]: 2
[Mono] Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Linq.Expressions' (System.Linq.Expressions.dll)
[Mono] Assembly System.Linq.Expressions[0x83e78c00] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT: image 'System.Linq.Expressions.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/com.companyname.peaceapp.peaceapp-25/libaot-System.Linq.Expressions.dll.so" not found
[Mono] AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/System.Linq.Expressions.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/com.companyname.peaceapp.peaceapp-25/libaot-System.Linq.Expressions.dll.so" not found
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: 'System.Linq.Expressions.dll.config'.
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Linq.Expressions/System.Linq.Expressions.config'.
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Newtonsoft.Json[0x7db5a818] -> System.Linq.Expressions[0x83e78c00]: 2
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.Linq.Expressions[0x83e78c00] -> System.Core[0x7efed490]: 7
Loaded assembly: System.Linq.Expressions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly [External]
[Mono] Image addref System.Reflection.Primitives[0x83fe3578] -> System.Reflection.Primitives.dll[0x83fe2f88]: 2
[Mono] Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Reflection.Primitives' (System.Reflection.Primitives.dll)
[Mono] Assembly System.Reflection.Primitives[0x83fe3578] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT: image 'System.Reflection.Primitives.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/com.companyname.peaceapp.peaceapp-25/libaot-System.Reflection.Primitives.dll.so" not found
[Mono] AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/System.Reflection.Primitives.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/com.companyname.peaceapp.peaceapp-25/libaot-System.Reflection.Primitives.dll.so" not found
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: 'System.Reflection.Primitives.dll.config'.
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Reflection.Primitives/System.Reflection.Primitives.config'.
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Newtonsoft.Json[0x7db5a818] -> System.Reflection.Primitives[0x83fe3578]: 2
Loaded assembly: System.Reflection.Primitives.dll [External]
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.Reflection.Primitives[0x83fe3578] -> mscorlib[0x737bb290]: 58
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.Collections[0x7ef3daf8] -> System.Core[0x7efed490]: 8
[Choreographer] Skipped 87 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref peaceApp.Droid[0x7c7bc640] -> Glide[0x7da25b40]: 2
[RecyclerView] No adapter attached; skipping layout
[RecyclerView] No adapter attached; skipping layout
[ViewRootImpl] sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
[RecyclerView] No adapter attached; skipping layout
[RecyclerView] No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

**3rd Activity**

```
Loaded assembly: System.Numerics.dll [External]
[Mono] Unloading image System.Reflection.dll [0x82696200].
[Mono] Image addref System.Reflection[0x82695838] -> System.Reflection.dll[0x7ef44a48]: 5
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: 'System.Reflection.dll.config'.
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Reflection/System.Reflection.config'.
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Newtonsoft.Json[0x7db5a818] -> System.Reflection[0x7ef45668]: 3
[Mono] Unloading image System.Linq.dll [0x82696200].
[Mono] Image addref System.Linq[0x82696048] -> System.Linq.dll[0x7eff61a0]: 5
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: 'System.Linq.dll.config'.
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Linq/System.Linq.config'.
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Newtonsoft.Json[0x7db5a818] -> System.Linq[0x7efec330]: 3
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Newtonsoft.Json[0x7db5a818] -> System.Reflection.Extensions[0x7f01cad0]: 3
[Mono] Image addref System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter[0x826daa38] -> System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll[0x826d7e20]: 2
[Mono] Prepared to set up assembly 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter' (System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll)
[Mono] Assembly System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter[0x826daa38] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT: image 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/com.companyname.peaceapp.peaceapp-25/libaot-System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll.so" not found
[Mono] AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/com.companyname.peaceapp.peaceapp-25/libaot-System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll.so" not found
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll.config'.
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.config'.
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Newtonsoft.Json[0x7db5a818] -> System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter[0x826daa38]: 2
Loaded assembly: System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll [External]
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter[0x826daa38] -> System[0x82665978]: 4
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.ObjectModel[0x82664640] -> mscorlib[0x737bb290]: 56
[Mono] Image addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0x83e5cb80] -> System.Runtime.Serialization.dll[0x83e457f0]: 2
[Mono] Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization' (System.Runtime.Serialization.dll)
[Mono] Assembly System.Runtime.Serialization[0x83e5cb80] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT: image 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/com.companyname.peaceapp.peaceapp-25/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so" not found
[Mono] AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/com.companyname.peaceapp.peaceapp-25/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so" not found
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.config'.
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Runtime.Serialization/System.Runtime.Serialization.config'.
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives[0x83acfff8] -> System.Runtime.Serialization[0x83e5cb80]: 2
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0x83e5cb80] -> mscorlib[0x737bb290]: 57
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.Serialization.dll [External]
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.Core[0x7efed490] -> System[0x82665978]: 5
[Mono] Image addref System.Linq.Expressions[0x83e78c00] -> System.Linq.Expressions.dll[0x83e94518]: 2
[Mono] Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Linq.Expressions' (System.Linq.Expressions.dll)
[Mono] Assembly System.Linq.Expressions[0x83e78c00] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT: image 'System.Linq.Expressions.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/com.companyname.peaceapp.peaceapp-25/libaot-System.Linq.Expressions.dll.so" not found
[Mono] AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/System.Linq.Expressions.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/com.companyname.peaceapp.peaceapp-25/libaot-System.Linq.Expressions.dll.so" not found
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: 'System.Linq.Expressions.dll.config'.
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Linq.Expressions/System.Linq.Expressions.config'.
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Newtonsoft.Json[0x7db5a818] -> System.Linq.Expressions[0x83e78c00]: 2
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.Linq.Expressions[0x83e78c00] -> System.Core[0x7efed490]: 7
Loaded assembly: System.Linq.Expressions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly [External]
[Mono] Image addref System.Reflection.Primitives[0x83fe3578] -> System.Reflection.Primitives.dll[0x83fe2f88]: 2
[Mono] Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Reflection.Primitives' (System.Reflection.Primitives.dll)
[Mono] Assembly System.Reflection.Primitives[0x83fe3578] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
[Mono] AOT: image 'System.Reflection.Primitives.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/com.companyname.peaceapp.peaceapp-25/libaot-System.Reflection.Primitives.dll.so" not found
[Mono] AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/System.Reflection.Primitives.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app-lib/com.companyname.peaceapp.peaceapp-25/libaot-System.Reflection.Primitives.dll.so" not found
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: 'System.Reflection.Primitives.dll.config'.
[Mono] Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Reflection.Primitives/System.Reflection.Primitives.config'.
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Newtonsoft.Json[0x7db5a818] -> System.Reflection.Primitives[0x83fe3578]: 2
Loaded assembly: System.Reflection.Primitives.dll [External]
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.Reflection.Primitives[0x83fe3578] -> mscorlib[0x737bb290]: 58
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.Collections[0x7ef3daf8] -> System.Core[0x7efed490]: 8
[Choreographer] Skipped 87 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref peaceApp.Droid[0x7c7bc640] -> Glide[0x7da25b40]: 2
[RecyclerView] No adapter attached; skipping layout
[RecyclerView] No adapter attached; skipping layout
[ViewRootImpl] sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
[RecyclerView] No adapter attached; skipping layout
[RecyclerView] No adapter attached; skipping layout
[Mono] GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 48 objects 78 opaque 171 colors 48 colors-bridged 48 colors-visible 48 xref 16 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.07ms tarjan 0.30ms scc-setup 0.04ms gather-xref 0.00ms xref-setup 0.00ms cleanup 0.03ms
[Mono] GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 22.76ms
[Mono] GC_MAJOR: (user request) time 3.58ms, stw 4.17ms los size: 1024K in use: 43K
[Mono] GC_MAJOR_SWEEP: major size: 928K in use: 218K
Thread started:  #3
[RecyclerView] No adapter attached; skipping layout
[RecyclerView] No adapter attached; skipping layout
[RecyclerView] No adapter attached; skipping layout
[RecyclerView] No adapter attached; skipping layout
[Mono] GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 121 objects 176 opaque 339 colors 121 colors-bridged 121 colors-visible 121 xref 40 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.06ms tarjan 0.25ms scc-setup 0.07ms gather-xref 0.01ms xref-setup 0.02ms cleanup 0.06ms
[Mono] GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 29.28ms
[Mono] GC_MAJOR: (user request) time 2.82ms, stw 3.37ms los size: 1024K in use: 43K
[Mono] GC_MAJOR_SWEEP: major size: 928K in use: 255K
Thread started:  #4
[ProgressBar] updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
[ProgressBar] updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
[ProgressBar] updateDrawableBounds: right = 144
[ProgressBar] updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 144
[RecyclerView] No adapter attached; skipping layout
[RecyclerView] No adapter attached; skipping layout
[ViewRootImpl] sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
[RecyclerView] No adapter attached; skipping layout
[RecyclerView] No adapter attached; skipping layout
[RecyclerView] No adapter attached; skipping layout
[RecyclerView] No adapter attached; skipping layout
[Mono] GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 143 objects 224 opaque 508 colors 143 colors-bridged 143 colors-visible 143 xref 55 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.06ms tarjan 0.24ms scc-setup 0.08ms gather-xref 0.01ms xref-setup 0.00ms cleanup 0.05ms
[Mono] GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 28.35ms
[Mono] GC_MAJOR_SWEEP: major size: 976K in use: 314K
[Mono] GC_MAJOR: (user request) time 3.44ms, stw 3.78ms los size: 1024K in use: 43K
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
[Mono] Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_boolean_method_a'.
[Mono] Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_boolean_method_a'.
[Mono] Found as 'java_interop_jnienv_call_boolean_method_a'.
[ProgressBar] updateDrawableBounds: left = 72
[ProgressBar] updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
[ProgressBar] updateDrawableBounds: right = 72
[ProgressBar] updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 0
```

**2nd Activity**

```
    protected override  void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {


        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity2);


        LoadData();

        rv = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);
        rv.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }

    private void changeState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Action selected:  ",
        ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(Rss_to_json);
        strBuilder.Append(URL from internet);

        new LoadDataAsync(this).Execute(strBuilder.ToString());

    }

    class LoadDataAsync : AsyncTask<string, string, string>

    {
        MainActivity mainActivity;
        ProgressDialog mDialog;

        public LoadDataAsync(MainActivity mainActivity){

            this.mainActivity = mainActivity;

        }

        protected override void OnPreExecute(){

            mDialog = new ProgressDialog(mainActivity);
            mDialog.Window.SetType(Android.Views.WindowManagerTypes.SystemAlert);
            mDialog.SetMessage("Please Wait.......");
            mDialog.Show();

        }

        protected override string RunInBackground(params string[] @params)
        {
            string result = new HTTPDataHandler().GetHTTPData(@params[0]);
            return result;
        }

        protected override void OnPostExecute(string result){

            RssObject data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RssObject>(result);
            mDialog.Dismiss();
            MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(data, mainActivity);
            mainActivity.rv.SetAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();


        }

    }

    private void login_User(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(LoginActivity));
        this.StartActivity(intent);
    }       

    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Action selected: " + item.TitleFormatted,
        ToastLength.Short).Show();



        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
            case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
                mDrawerLayout.OpenDrawer((int)GravityFlags.Left);
                return true;

            case Resource.Id.loginUser:

                Intent user = new Intent(this, typeof(LoginActivity));
                this.StartActivity(user);

                return true;


            default:
                return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.main_menu, menu);
        return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    private void SetUpDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView)
    {
        navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += (object sender, NavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            int id = e.MenuItem.ItemId;

            switch(id){


                case Resource.Id.activity2:

                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(activity2));
                    this.StartActivity(intent);
                    GC.Collect();

                    break;





                case Resource.Id.activity3:
                    Intent photos = new Intent(this, typeof(activity3));
                    this.StartActivity(photos);
                    GC.Collect();

                    break;



            }



            e.MenuItem.SetChecked(true);
            mDrawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
        };
    }


}
```

**3rd Activity**

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity3);

        this.refreshAll();

        FloatingActionButton fab = FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.fab);

        fab.Click += delegate {
            LayoutInflater eInflater = LayoutInflater.From(this);
            View mView = eInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.PeaceHeroDialog, null);
            Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alertDialogBuilder.SetView(mView);



            alertDialogBuilder.SetCancelable(false)
                              .SetPositiveButton("Save", async delegate
                              {
                                    //save details into firebase


                                  var firebase = new FirebaseClient(FirebaseUrl);
                                  var item = await firebase.Child("Table").PostAsync<someArray>(add);

                                        await RefreshData();

                              })

                              .SetNegativeButton("Cancel", delegate
                              {

                                  alertDialogBuilder.Dispose();

                              });

            Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog alertDialogAndroid = alertDialogBuilder.Create();
            alertDialogAndroid.Show();


        };

    }

    //refresh data

    private  async void refreshAll(){

        await RefreshData();


    }


    private async Task RefreshData()
    {

        circular_progress.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        rv.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;

        var firebase = new FirebaseClient(FirebaseUrl);

        var items = await firebase.Child("table").OnceAsync<something>();

        itemsToBeAdded.Clear();

        refreshAdapter = null;

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
           //code to fetch data from firebase

        }

        refreshAdapter = new PeaceHeroAdapter(itemToBeAdded, this );
        rv.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        rv.SetItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        rv.SetAdapter(refreshAdapter);

        refreshAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

        circular_progress.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;

        rv.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;


    }



}
```

Comment: Could you paste your code please?

Comment: @Marc i have updated the question with codes for activity 2 and activity3.

Comment: Try moving the `LoadData()` method to the `OnResume()`. Same for the `this.refreshAll();`.  Doing heavy transactions on the OnCreate is not a good idea since this is the moment where the UI is being inflated.

Comment: Well, I'm not entirely sure if this is where all the slowdown is, but you are doing your data deserialization on the main thread in your onPostExecute, right? Maybe you might get better performance by keeping the deserialization in the async task. Then return the result from the background task to the onPostExecute method.

Comment: @Marc, if i get your comment right, it is just like how i have actually posted. Deserialization happens in  in my `onPostExecute` and the results from the background is passed to the the `onPostExecute`

Comment: @apineda, using the OnResume method, the app lags once after it is created. Thereafter, there is smooth movement. But why would it lag once after the OnCreate is ran and thereafter perform smoothly? Can't i make it  perform better and not lag ?

Comment: RssObject data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RssObject>(result); is done in the OnPostExecute. I am saying you could do that in the RunInBackground method, then return the deserialized data object to OnPostExecute